# Regular Expression for validate price in decimal

Tags: objective-c, regex

I really unable to find any  workaround for regular expression to input price in decimal.
This what I want:-

12345

12345.1

12345.12

12345.123

.123

0.123

I also want to restrict digits.

I really created one but not validating as assumed

**^([0-9]{1,5}|([0-9]{1,5}\.([0-9]{1,3})))$**

Also want to know how is above expression different from the one

**^([0-9]{1,5}|([0-9].([0-9]{1,3})))$** thats working fine.

Anyone with good explanation.

**"I am using NSRegularExpression - Objective C" if this helps to answer more precisely**

```
- (IBAction)btnTapped {

      NSRegularExpression * regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:
         @"^\\d{1,5}([.]\\d{1,3})?|[.]\\d{1,3}$" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];

     if ([regex numberOfMatchesInString:txtInput.text options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [txtInput.text length])]) 
         NSLog(@"Matched : %@",txtInput.text);
     else
        NSLog(@"Not Matched : %@",txtInput.text);
}
```

**"I am doing it in a buttonTap method".**

Comment: If an answer suited your needs, instead of putting it in your original question as you've done, you should better [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). That way, you're question will be marked as *resolved* and could then be useful to other people. Same for the other questions you already asked.

Comment: I really mistakenly added your expression,,,,,apologies for same

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This simple one should suit your needs:

```
\d*[.]?\d+
```

*"Digits (`\d+`) that can be preceded by a dot (`[.]?`), which can itself be preceded by digits (`\d*`)."*

Since you're talking about prices, neither scientific notation nor negative numbers are necessary.

---

Just as a point of interest, here's the one I usually used, scientific notation and negative numbers included:

```
[-+]?\d*[.]?\d+(?:[eE][-+]?\d+)?
```

---

For the new requirements (cf. comments), you can't specify how many digits you want on the first regex I gave, since it's not the way it has been *built*.

This one should suit your needs better:

```
\d{1,5}([.]\d{1,3})?|[.]\d{1,3}
```

*"Max 5 digits (`\d{1,5}`) possibly followed (`(...)?`) by a dot itself followed by max 3 digits (`[.]\d{1,3}`), or (`|`) simply a dot followed by max 3 digits (`[.]\d{1,3}`)"*.

Comment: Ahahaha, this neglects the possiblity of a (optional) whitespace between +/- and the first number...

Comment: Oh wait, I'm wrong, double.TryParse also doesn't take a whitespace in between - and the number. Filed bug 785552 for the .NET framework :)

Comment: tried with 123, 123.45 didn't work using NSRegularExpression - Objective C,,,unsolved still...

Comment: @gagansharma I never used NSRegularExpression, but maybe you have to double-escape the backslashes: `\\d*[.]?\\d+`. Please try and let me know.

Comment: Yeah some breakthrough...it worked great..but i want to <max digit 5>.<max digit 3> that is without fraction max total size "5" ,with fraction max size is 8 (12345.123)..Thanks

Comment: I am trying to restrict digits with \\d{0,10}[.]?\\d{1,3}..but no luck so far...waiting for a hint enthusiastically...!

Comment: I tried your exp by putting one more backslashes \\d{1,5}([.]\\d{1,3})?|[.]\\d{1,3}.....but did n't work...We are almost there but I think missing something...."twist in the tales"..#

Comment: @gagansharma Which input string didn't match this regex? And could you provide the code you're using to match the string (put it in your question)?

Comment: should not match input strings **123456,0.1234**

Comment: @gagansharma If you want to use anchors (`^` or `$`), use surrounding parentheses since there's a logical OR `|`. Try `^(\\d{1,5}([.]\\d{1,3})?|[.]\\d{1,3})$`

Answer (score 1):

Let's do this *per-partes*:

- Sign in the beginning: `[+-]?`
- Fraction number: `\.\d+`
- Possible combinations (after sign):

  - Number: `\d+`
  - Fraction without zero `\.\d+`
  - And number with fraction: `\d+\.\d+`

So to join it all together `<sign>(number|fraction without zero|number with fraction)`:

```
^[+-]?(\d+|\.\d+|\d+\.\d+)$
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this: `^([+-])?(\d+)?([.,])?(\d+)?$`

```
            string input = "bla";
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
            {
                string pattern = @"^(\s+)?([-])?(\s+)?(\d+)?([,.])?(\d+)(\s+)?$";

                input = input.Replace("\'", ""); // Remove thousand's separator
                System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern);
                // if server culture = de then reverse the below replace
                input = input.Replace(',', '.');
            }
```

**Edit:**
Oh oh - just realized that's where we run into a little bit of a problem if an en-us user uses ',' as thousand's separator....

So here a better one:

```
        string input = "+123,456";
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
        {
            string pattern = @"^(\s+)?([+-])?(\s+)?(\d+)?([.,])?(\d+)(\s+)?$";

            input = input.Replace(',', '.'); // Ensure no en-us thousand's separator
            input = input.Replace("\'", ""); // Remove thousand's separator
            input = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(input, @"\s", ""); // Remove whitespaces

            bool foo = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern);
            if (foo)
            {
                bool de = false;
                if (de) // if server-culture = de
                    input = input.Replace('.', ',');

                double d = 0;
                bool bar = double.TryParse(input, out d);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(foo == bar);

                Console.WriteLine(foo);
                Console.WriteLine(input);
            }
            else
                throw new ArgumentException("input");
        }
        else
            throw new NullReferenceException("input");
```

**Edit2:**
Instead of going through the hassle of getting the server culture, just use the tryparse overload with the culture and don't resubstitute the decimal separator.

```
double.TryParse(input 
               , System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any
               , new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")
               , out d
);
```

Comment: No need to put so many parentheses. Moreover, `(X+)?` should be reduced to `X*`. Exactly yours, but reduced: `^\s*[+-]?\s*\d*[.,]?\d+\s*?$`. Also, the *lazy match* of the last spaces isn't really necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not restricting the lengths to 5 digits before the decimal and 3 digits after then you could use this:

```
^[+-]?(?:[0-9]*\.[0-9]|[0-9]+)$
```

If you are restricting it to 5 before and 3 after max then you'd need something like this:

```
^[+-]?(?:[0-9]{0,5}\.[0-9]{1,3}|[0-9]{1,5})$
```

As far as the difference between your regexes goes, the first one limits the length of the number of digits before the decimal marker to 1-5 with and without decimals present. The second one only allows a single digit in front of the decimal pointer and 1-5 digits if there is no decimal.